# Sort by column group and ignore other columns failing for this example, why?

Tags: text-processing, sort

I cannot work out why `sort` is not working correctly for this, but it's sorting based on columns I'm telling it not to. I want to sort with priorities first by column 3, then column 4, then column 5, then column 6. What's going on?

Here is my code: `sort -n -s -t ',' -k3,6`

Here is my input:

```
a1,b1,2,15,50,ABBA    
a1,a1,2,26,55,ABBA    
a11,2a1,2,33,55,ABBA   
b1,a1,2,80,99,ABA   
c2,a1,3,20,40,CAN   
a1,b2,3,51,300,CAN   
a3,a3,4,1000,2000,ART   
d3,c3,4,1700,2050,ART   
d3,c2c,4,1600,2050,ART   
b1,a3,4,1800,2051,ART
```

Here is my current output:

```
a1,b1,2,15,50,ABBA   
a1,a1,2,26,55,ABBA   
a11,2a1,2,33,55,ABBA   
b1,a1,2,80,99,ABA   
c2,a1,3,20,40,CAN   
a1,b2,3,51,300,CAN   
a3,a3,4,1000,2000,ART   
d3,c3,4,1700,2050,ART 
d3,c2c,4,1600,2050,ART
b1,a3,4,1800,2051,ART
```

but my desired and expected output should be:

```
a1,b1,2,15,50,ABBA   
a1,a1,2,26,55,ABBA   
a11,2a1,2,33,55,ABBA   
b1,a1,2,80,99,ABA   
c2,a1,3,20,40,CAN   
a1,b2,3,51,300,CAN   
a3,a3,4,1000,2000,ART   
d3,c2c,4,1600,2050,ART    
d3,c3,4,1700,2050,ART
b1,a3,4,1800,2051,ART
```

I am using Linux.

Comment: `-k3,6` means third to sixth column. Did you mean `-k3,3`?

Comment: Yes, please [edit] your question and explain how you want this sorted.

Comment: Hi, sorry, yes I want lines sorted by columns 3,4,5,and 6. So first group by column 3, and within those groups group by column 4 etc etc. I've adjusted my question to be clearer now

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is that your sorting key is a string containing commas.

When comparing two of these keys, like `4,1700,2050,ART` and `4,1600,2050,ART`, they compare *equal* since (in your locale) only the very first part of the keys can be converted to a numeric value (4, and 4).

To solve this, compare each field separately with the correct type for that field (numeric or non-numeric):

```bash
sort -s -t, -k3,3n -k4,4n -k5,5n -k6,6 file
```

---

Most implementations of `sort` provide a `--debug` option that is very helpful for detecting issues like these. On my FreeBSD system, this clearly shows that your original command has issues when comparing fields like the ones I mentioned:

```bash
$ sort --debug -n -s -t ',' -k3,6 file
[...]
; k1=<4,1000,2000,ART   >, k2=<4,1700,2050,ART   >; s1=<a3,a3,4,1000,2000,ART   >, s2=<d3,c3,4,1700,2050,ART   >; cmp1=0
; k1=<4,1700,2050,ART   >, k2=<4,1600,2050,ART   >; s1=<d3,c3,4,1700,2050,ART   >, s2=<d3,c2c,4,1600,2050,ART   >; cmp1=0
; k1=<4,1600,2050,ART   >, k2=<4,1800,2051,ART   >; s1=<d3,c2c,4,1600,2050,ART   >, s2=<b1,a3,4,1800,2051,ART   >; cmp1=0
[...]
```

`cmp1=0` shows that the keys, `k1` and `k2`, compares equal.

As a comparison:

```bash
$ sort --debug -s -t, -k3,3n -k4,4n -k5,5n -k6,6 file
[...]
; k1=<4>, k2=<4>; k1=<1000>, k2=<1700>; s1=<a3,a3,4,1000,2000,ART   >, s2=<d3,c3,4,1700,2050,ART   >; cmp1=-1
; k1=<4>, k2=<4>; k1=<1700>, k2=<1600>; s1=<d3,c3,4,1700,2050,ART   >, s2=<d3,c2c,4,1600,2050,ART   >; cmp1=1
; k1=<4>, k2=<4>; k1=<1000>, k2=<1600>; s1=<a3,a3,4,1000,2000,ART   >, s2=<d3,c2c,4,1600,2050,ART   >; cmp1=-1
; k1=<4>, k2=<4>; k1=<1700>, k2=<1800>; s1=<d3,c3,4,1700,2050,ART   >, s2=<b1,a3,4,1800,2051,ART   >; cmp1=-1
[...]
```

GNU `sort` likely produces debug output in a totally different format.

Comment: Fantastic, that fixed it! Terdon had the right idea but the individual column issue makes sense. Thank you

Comment: Duh, of course, the last one ins't numeric. Out of curiosity, what is your locale, @Giles? I'm guessing that something sorts differently in your locale compared to mine and that's why it was working as expected for me.

Comment: @terdon Is the comma (`,`) a decimal comma in some locales perhaps? This would make `4,1700` > `4,1600`.

Comment: Oooh, yes, that seems likely. It is indeed a decimal in some locales. Good catch.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are sorting lexically and not numerically. You need `-n` to sort numerically, otherwise `100` will be sorted before `123` or even `2`:

```
$ printf '2\n123\n100\n' | sort
100
123
2
```

But, with `-n`:

```
$ printf '2\n123\n100\n' | sort -n
2
100
123
```

So in your case, you need to add the `n` to the fields you want sorted numerically:

```
$ sort -t, -k3n,6n file  
a1,b1,2,15,50,ABBA    
a1,a1,2,26,55,ABBA    
a11,2a1,2,33,55,ABBA   
b1,a1,2,80,99,ABA   
c2,a1,3,20,40,CAN   
a1,b2,3,51,300,CAN   
a3,a3,4,1000,2000,ART   
d3,c2c,4,1600,2050,ART   
d3,c3,4,1700,2050,ART   
b1,a3,4,1800,2051,ART
```

Comment: Very cool, I didn't know you could treat the specific columns differently like that. However, I tried this on the example input and it placed 1800 before 1600 and 1700

Comment: @Giles I can't reproduce that on my system. What you see in my answer is the result of running that command on the input you provided. Maybe your real file is different?

Comment: Thats wierd, I even tried copying your output, mixing the lines up and running your answer and it still come out wrong. Now I'm worried theres something more fundementally wrong on my side. Perhaps my sort is broken, I'm baffled :(